# PayPal: Create and Capture Order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am following this sample (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/#on-the-server) to get PayPal working on the server.

I have finished creating the order, but it doesn't capture the order at the same time. Is it possible to create and capture the order at the same time?

```
var request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
request.Prefer("return=representation");
request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody());

var response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);  //this will only create the order. How to capture it at the same time?
```

When I tried to capture the order:

```
//continue from above
var result = response.Result<Order>();

var requestCapture = new OrdersCaptureRequest(result.Id);
requestCapture.Prefer("return=representation");
requestCapture.RequestBody(new OrderActionRequest());

response = await PayPalClient.Client().Execute(requestCapture);
```

I get the error:

```
"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
"details":  [{
                "issue":"ORDER_NOT_APPROVED",
                "description":"Payer has not yet approved the Order for payment. Please redirect the payer to the 'rel':'approve' url returned as part of the HATEOAS links within the Create Order call or provide a valid payment_source in the request."
            }],
"message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
"links":    [{
                "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-ORDER_NOT_APPROVED",
                "rel": "information_link",
                "method": "GET"
            }]
```

My question is, is it possible to create order, authorize and capture at the ***same*** time?

Thanks

Comment: i cant even get a response back from var response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request); :(

Comment: it should give you some sort of response even if it doesn't work (eg. timeout). What response did you get?

Comment: Thats what i dont get this call, var response = await PayPalHttpClient(currentShoppingCart).Execute(request); goes and never gets back, i can see the request in the sandbox API calls with orange exclamation mark warning and no clue what the problem is :(

Comment: Does it hang? it might not because of paypal. It might be because of deadlock... did you call this function via `async` function or did you create `Task` to call `await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);`?

Comment: sorry had parked this for a bit for some more crucial work, so basically had an async task which i had set to return the order if it had a success status back. When i left it had noticed there was an error being thrown as i was setting my currency to AUD, and all Prices had to also be AUD, but even when i changed this and the request in paypal sandbox was now going green (instead of orange) still wasnt getting the order back till at least about a good 30+ secs which just isnt practical :(

Answer (score 0):

Before using `OrdersCaptureRequest`, you have to redirect to [rel] => approve link from the response of `OrdersCreateRequest`:

```
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    $res_links = $response->result->links;
    $approve_index = array_search('approve',array_column($res_links,'rel'));
    redirect($res_links[$approve_index]->href,'location',302);`
```

And *then* use `OrdersCaptureRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to create, authorize and capture order at the same time in PayPal, even in sandbox environment. You'll have to follow each step separately.
And about the `ORDER_NOT_APPROVED` error, you can either get the order approved by the user as @raj-kamal said, or you can make a `Paypal-Auth-Assertion` and send it in the headers. This header is an API client-provided JSON Web Token (JWT) assertion that identifies the merchant.

Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-requests/#paypal-auth-assertion

NOTE:

> To use this header, you must get consent to act on behalf of a merchant.